# How do I install an apk on PC

Tags: apk, operating-system

I am having trouble installing apk files on my PC which has Windows 7 OS .The apk files are backups from my android mobile. After double clicking the apk files it starts initializing and automatically opens the Google Play Store.

Comment: Are you trying to install an android application directly onto a Windows machine? You can't do that. Are you running the android emulator or are you just trying to use apps on a PC?

Comment: i m just trying to use app on pc

Comment: It can't be done, they are written and developed for an entirely different operating system. You can't install Android apps on Windows, iOS, Linux, UNIX, AIX or any other OS. Much like you can't install Windows apps on Android (or iOS etc).

Comment: what can i do now to run android apps on windows??

Comment: You could install the Android SDK, boot up the emulator and try to run the APK that way. Or, you could use BlueStacks (http://www.bluestacks.com/) and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: i have downloaded bluestack but it doesn't works.After double clicking the apk file,bluestack start initializing and opens play store.

Comment: Nope, you can't install apk file over the desktop, what are going to require is the emulator to do that !

Comment: what is emulator?

Comment: i have got it..

Answer (score 2):

You are first going to need to install an emulator like [BlueStacks](https://bluestacks.com/), [GenyMotion](https://genymotion.com/), or AVD (from the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)).

With any of these emulators, the most universal way is from the **ADB** tool. This tool can be found in the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) or from a program like [Minimal ADB and Fastboot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790).

In the ADB directory, run the following code after connecting your device to the computer:

```
adb install app.apk
```

replacing `app.apk` with the full path to the .apk you are trying to install.